# GOOGLE SHEETS Search cells and sort and sum diffrent name

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-api, googlesheets4

Please let me know if it is possible for Google Sheets to sort data separated by "|" and then sum all unique values counting with multiplier. The multiplier is specified with "#". I am sending an example photo of the input data and what I would like to receive.
[image]

I can separate the values ​​using the "SPLIT" function, but I still have the names with the multiplier in front.

[image]

Comment: I think your question needs a bit of clarification... I'm struggling to wrap my head around exactly what you're trying to do. REGEXEXTRACT will likely be useful here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am sure someone will give you prettier solution but:

```
=let(ars,arrayformula(split(tocol((SPLIT(A1:A3,"|")),3),"#")),byrow(unique(choosecols(ars,2)),lambda(uq,HSTACK(sumproduct((uq=choosecols(ars,2))*choosecols(ars,1)),uq))))
```

Result:

[image]